# saving NSString to files which remain even when the app is killed by iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to implement an iOs App which stores (text) data depending on certain locations. My problem is that if my app get killed by iOS all the data are lost. Right now I am using document directory to store my txt files. No problem as long as app is alive...
My question is where should i store my txt files to keep it even in case of app gets terminated?

Comment: They should exits in Documents directory even after your apps gets killed.

Comment: Are you meaning killed to be when the process is terminated or when your app is uninstalled? Your application's Documents directory is permanent, as long as your app is not uninstalled.

Comment: Actually i am happy about these answers. So something is wrong. Is there a difference how to kill the app. I am storing my stuff in applicationWillTerminate method in app delegate. And i am killing the app by pressing the home button and then drag it upwards out of the screen. Is this the same effect like killed by iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Mappet?

By "killed" do you mean "stopped, no longer running" or "removed from the iOS-device"?
The reply from Priyatham51 reflects on your App on longer running, but still being on the iOS device (and a user could start it again).
If you want the data to survive the App being remove from the Device you may want to look into storing the NSString into iCloud (you could start with something like https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php).

Bart-Jan.

Comment: i mean app stays on the device but stopped by pressing home button and drag it out of the screen (iOS7)

Answer (score 0):

Data saved in the Document directory should be alive even after your app gets killed. You might be doing something wrong in your code.

From Apple Doc

Application_Home>/Documents/
Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user-generated content.
The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code that writes string to text file. I have also used NSDocumentoryDirectory. Please let me know if you still find a problem in writing to text file.

```
NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Documents directory %@",documentsDirectory);
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.txt",
                      documentsDirectory];
NSString *content=@"Hello World";
[content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```